# How do I run a PHP script from cron?

Tags: bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Are my paths correct? PHP file doesn't run and no errors in apache error or syslog.

```
*/5 * 10 10 * bitnami /home/bitnami/stack/php/bin/php -q /home/bitnami/htdocs/mailer.php
```

Comment: Hi, Bitnami Engineer here. In case you are using a cloud image or a virtual machine, the PHP binary is at `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php`. In case you used a native installer in your local computer, please note that the bitnami user is not in the machine unless you created it. In order to debug the issue, you can redirect the output of the command to a file in your home directory and check what the issue is `/home/bitnami/stack/php/bin/php -q /home/bitnami/htdocs/mailer.php >> /home/bitnami/output 2>&1`

Comment: This is AWS Lightsail. In fact the path in my question works.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Did you redirect the command's output to a file and check if after the cron daemon ran it? You'll probably get the error message in that file.

Comment: In fact the results of the PHP file called from cron were being written to a different file than I expected because I didn't specify the path properly.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I thought I'd share my solution for this exact same setup. I believe Bitnami's current generation of cron installation doesn't support the format "*/5". What I had to do instead is "0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * 10 10 * bitnami...." which gives the intended result of running every 5 minutes.